# Bind <return> to newline-and-indent, but also have it used in minibuffer?

Tags: emacs

Can I bind  (Enter) to newline-and-indent, but also have it work as usual in the minibuffer?

Comment: Did you try it out and noticed if it worked?

Comment: And I do that how? Binding it to push-button and newline-and-indent doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is to bind it to `newline-and-indent` for the major modes that you use, and leave the default binding as it is.

You can bind it in a major mode *hook* or use `eval-after-load`.